# RN - this.state with dynamic key

Tags: react-native

Im loading a view in flatlist, which i have different style for each progressCircle1,progressCircle2,progressCircle3.

```
backgroundColor: this.state.progressCircle1
```

Is there such method where i can use renderItem, item.id to the state name?

example:
backgroundColor: this.state.progressCircle[item.id]

Comment: How about `this.state={ this.state.arrProgressCircle: [] }`, `this.state.arrProgressCircle[index]`

Comment: as your example, you can assign an array to your state and use any index of it based on item.id

Comment: i solve it by using it this way : this.state['progressCircle' + item.id]